# How to use python to make a http client that sends multiple cookie headers

Tags: python, http, cookies, http-headers

I tried the following code:

```
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'foo',
           'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
           'Accept': 'text/html',
           'Cookie': 'cookie_1=blah',
           'Cookie': cookie_2=haha',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

And then use

```
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(host)
conn.request('GET', path, headers=headers)
```

to send the request.

But in the request headers, I only got 'Cookie: cookie_2=haha'

How to make the client send something like:

```
Cookie: cookie_1=blah\r\n
Cookie: cookie_2=haha\r\n
```

Is that possible in python? Thanks.

Comment: The usual syntax is `Cookie: cookie_1=blah; cookie_2=haha\r\n`. Is this perhaps something you want instead?

Comment: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-November/591274.html

Comment: @Caramiriel No. I want to have two separate cookie headers